# Jupyter using the wrong version of python

Tags: python, python-2.6, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Hi I've installed python 2.7 but did not remove 2.6. i've added 2.7 to the path and also as an alias but it seems like when I do jupyter notebook it tries to access 2.6

```
> jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
 from notebook.notebookapp import main
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/notebook/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 226, in  <module>
from traitlets import Bool, Enum, Unicode
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/traitlets/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .traitlets import *
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1291
return {n: t for (n, t) in cls.class_traits(**metadata).items()
               ^
```

My python version seems to point to 2.7

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

as well as my which python seems to give the right out put :

```
$ which python
alias python='/usr/local/bin/python2.7'
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

I have pip installed for both versions of python. I am not sure how to fix this :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It could be a problem in your python kernel.json configuration. For example my python kernel is located at:

```
/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python/kernel.json
```

and contains:

```
    {
     "language": "python",
     "display_name": "Python 2.7",
     "argv": [
      "/usr/local/bin/python2.7",
      "-m",
      "ipykernel",
      "-f",
      "{connection_file}"
     ]
    }
```

Make sure that the path in **argv** section points to correct version of python.

Comment: This was helpful.  For Windows users, the path to your kernel.json might be something like this: C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\pythonX where x is python 2 or 3.

Comment: there is no kernels folder in AppData\Roaming\jupyter

Comment: I didn't find any folder at /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python/

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you installed jupyter as an extension of `/usr/lib/python2.6`. If so, you'd have to uninstall jupyter and reinstall into your desired python.

```bash
/usr/lib/python2.6 -m pip uninstall jupyter && python -m pip install jupyter
```

Comment: even after uninstalling jupyter and reinstalling in python 3.8, it's still trying to launch nonexistant "C:\program files\python37\python.exe"