# Running jupyter notebook in a virtualenv (with permission issue)

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I am trying to run jupyter notebook in a virtualenv on a cloud computing platform running Linux, but I am unable to install a ipykernel for jupyter notebook.

Here are the steps that I have done:

1. Install a virtual environment for python 3 at my local storage space. The tag `--system-site-packages` has been used, to minimize the size of the virtual environment folder. So it should inherit the global python 3.6 and libraries.
2. Activated the virtual environment, installed sympy, started `python3`, `import sympy` and it worked. (Note that without the virtualenv, pip does not work as we have no permission to write to the global version of python)
3. Tried to run `jupyter notebook` in the same virtual environment, but trying to `import sympy` returns `No module named 'sympy'`. Using `print(sys.executable)` reveals that it is running on the global python3.6. (When running `python3` in virtualenv and printing executable, it prints the path of python3 in `myvirtualenv/bin/python3`)
4. Tried to follow [these instructions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496350/execute-python-script-within-jupyter-notebook-using-a-specific-virtualenv?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) `pip install jupyter` and `pip install ipykernel` worked properly, saying requirement already satisfied. But `python -m ipykernel install --user --name testenv --display-name "MyEnv"` does not work, returning

`` [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/tmpc2ebdyp9_kernels/python3/kernel.json'
Perhaps you want `sudo` or `--user`? ``

which really confuses me, as I thought the --user tag should make it install at my local directory already. I also tried specifying the path of my virtualenv by using `--prefix`, but it is still saying I have no permission to access the system's `kernel.json`.

I also tried `ipython kernel install --name "xx" --user` and specifying path with `--prefix` but it returns the same error.

**So my question is:**

1. Did this error arise because even though the ipython kernel was installed locally, the `kernel.json` at the system directory still needs to be changed? Or did the tags `--user` or `--prefix` not work for some reason?
2. How can I create a kernel truly locally? I suppose after that I can create my own `kernel.json` as in [here](https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2014/09/01/ipython_kernel/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561126/jupyter-using-the-wrong-version-of-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to direct the jupyter notebook to use my own kernel?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Any suggestion/advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: Note that I am running this on a public cluster, so I don't really have permission to the files at /tmp.
I tried to chmod the specific files, but then it seems like it didn't actually change the permission, and that a new temp files is generated every time I run the python -m ipykernel install xxx ...