# No module named 'requests' in Jupyter with Python3, but "Requirement already satisfied" for Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm on a macOS with Catalina, running my environment from `venv`. I'm trying to `import requests` within a Jupyter notebook Python3, but I'm getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-95039fbd75c1> in <module>()
----> 1 import requests

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

However, `requests` is already installed for Python3:

```
(venv) 42piratas@Darkseid PLAYGROUND % pip3 install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests) (1.25.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from requests) (2020.6.20)
```

If I try to import `requests` from the terminal or from a script, it works for Python3, but it won't work for the native macos Python either. But as I said above, I'm using a Python3 notebook

And just in case, if I run the code below within the notebook...

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
```

...I get `3.6.5`

**UPDATE/FIXED:**
As pointed out below by @m-z below, my Python3 is v3.8 and Jupyter was running v3.6. To fix this, I had to change one "kernel.json" file, as explained in this thread: [Jupyter using the wrong version of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561126/jupyter-using-the-wrong-version-of-python)

Comment: your pip is installing it for `python3.8`, and also in a virtualenv, whereas your notebook is `python3.6.5`. Make sure you pip install for the right environment and the right version of python

Comment: It seems you are correct. But how do I point Jupyter to the correct (the latest installed) Python3 version?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't use the virtual environment `venv` when you launch the Jupyter Notebook.

There are two methods to solve this problem:

1. Create a Jupyter kernel

You can create a Jupyter kernel in your virtual environment.
This [blog](https://medium.com/@eleroy/jupyter-notebook-in-a-virtual-environment-virtualenv-8f3c3448247) maybe helpful.

2. Install `requests` in the exit Jupyter notebook

Run the following command in the Jupyter Notebook cell.

```
!pip3 install requests
```

Comment: Interesting, but if I try "!pip3 install requests" it returns "Requirement already satisfied" as well. As someone else pointed out in another answer, my venv is using Python3.8 but Jupyter, Python3.6

Comment: Did you try "!pip3 install requests"  in Jupyter notebook cell?

Comment: Yes, I did. And the notebook returns "Requirements already satisfied", but keeps saying right after "no module named 'requests". https://ibb.co/n8dG835

Comment: instead of `!pip`, use `%pip`. that will use the pip of the python that is running in jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

your pip is installing it for python3.8, and also in a virtualenv, whereas your notebook is python3.6.5. Make sure you pip install for the right environment and the right version of python
to do this uninstall the older version of python, then:

- Go to `C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\`  and revome the files of older version
- Try installing jupyter notebook by `pip install jupyter`
- Run jupyter notebook by code `jupyter notebook`
- Then again do `!pip install requests`
- `import requests`

Comment: instead of `!pip`, use `%pip`. that will use the pip of the python that is running in jupyter notebook.

Comment: Listen to @jakub and please when suggesting `pip` use, suggest the recently added magic commands added to help deal with installing to the correct backing environment automatically and not using the outdated exclamation point. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). It works with `conda` too. Often because of automagics being on by default, you can get away without any symbol for pip and conda these days and it will use the new magic commands behind-the-scenes.

Answer (score 0):

after instaling these libs:

```
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==8.2.0
jupyter-console==6.6.3
jupyter-core==5.3.0
```

I solved the problem of "No module named 'requests'" by installing all the packages that I need at a cell in Jupyter Notebook like:

```
!pip3 install requests
!pip3 install numpy
!pip3 install pandas 
!pip3 install xlsxwriter
```

then run the cell and you will be Okay.