# ModuleNotFound error in one jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, system, anaconda3, modulenotfounderror

I am facing this weird issue where I have a jupyter notebook which is giving me ModuleNotFound error on Library but I did not face same issue on other notebook.
Path for notebook1 is `C:\Users\Avinash Jha\Documents\Python\SB\GITHUB\project1\Notebooks\xyz.py`

[image]

Path for notebook2 is `C:\Users\Avinash Jha\Documents\Python\SB\GITHUB\project2\Notebooks\acb.py`

[image: Screenshot with error]

CMD screenshot when i tried to install the module.

[image]

Comment: hi, can you able to post error here in question?

Comment: Are you sure your version of python and the version that jupyter notebook is running are the same?

Comment: I have added the error screenshot. Please check.

Comment: Hi @Gurneetsingh, my python on jupyter is 3.7.6 and on system it is 3.7.4

Comment: @AvinashJha does this help you then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561126/jupyter-using-the-wrong-version-of-python

Answer (score 1):

May be your jupyter notebook is running in different virtual environment try to run same pip command from notebook with append '!' like this

```
!pip install library
```

Comment: What do you mean by different virtual environment?